# centOS recursive owner change

Tags: permissions, centos

My server guy did something really stupid, he changed accidently owner to root from /. Is it possible to undo recursive permissions change in centoOS? 
Im not sure what he typed but it should be something like:

```
chown -R root /
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "undo" permissions changes as nothing records the previous permissions. You can ask rpm to restore the permissions (and modes) of all the package installed files using the `--setperms` and `--setugids` arguments. For files that are manually installed/created/etc. you have to just know what they are supposed to be (or hope to have a backup with the permissions intact that you can use as a template or something).